# Dynamically loaded video source is aborted in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, video

I have a script that loads the sources for a video that works great in Chrome, FF and Safari. In IE however, the source is "Aborted" in the networks tab. Here is my code:

```
<div id="video_wrapper">
<video muted controls="false" autoplay poster="/videos/home.jpg" preload="none" loop id="bg_video">
    <img src="/videos/home.jpg" alt="Your browser does not support HTML5 video.">
</video>
```

```js
    documentObj.on('ready', function() {
  insertVideo();
 });

 
 
 function insertVideo() {
  if (windowObj.width() > 767) {
   
   setTimeout(function() {
    var video = $("video")[0];
    insertSource("/videos/home.webm", 'video/webm');
    insertSource("/videos/home.mp4", "video/mp4");
    video.play();
   }, 50);
  } else {
   $("video").remove();
  }
 }

 function insertSource(src, type) {
  var source = document.createElement('source');
  source.src = src;
  source.type = type;
  $("#bg_video").prepend(source);
 }
```

Anyone have any advice on this? I can't seem to figure this mess out.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: can you also please share the whole markup?

Comment: @Roman I added the HTML that is relevant to the js. I can add my entire HTML file but its around 400 lines long.

Comment: I tested this in IE11 and it's working fine. What version of IE are you testing?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding an event listener for "canplay" on the video element. Once its loaded, i ran video.play() and everything seems to be working fine.

Thanks everyone!